# how to replace the word and convert to pascal case in vs code snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have a snippet that is not working.
this snippet should convert the file name into pascal case
then remove the Impl word after implements

```json
"body": [
    "class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/g} implements ${${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/g}/(Impl)//} {",
    "final ${2:RemoteDataSource} remoteDataSource;",
    "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/g}({required this.remoteDataSource});",
    "}"],
```

Expected Result

```
class HomeRepositoryImpl implements HomeRepository {
  final HomeDataSource remoteDataSource;
  HomeRepositoryImpl({required this.remoteDataSource});
}
```

Actual Result

```
class HomeRepositoryImpl implements ${HomeRepositoryImpl/(Impl)//} {
    final RemoteDataSource remoteDataSource;
    HomeRepositoryImpl({required this.remoteDataSource});
   }
```

Comment: `${${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/g}/(Impl)//}` - if you were trying to nest a transform inside another transform here - that cannot be done.

Comment: and what is the solution to achieve that?

Comment: What is the filename you are starting from?  That would be helpful, so everyone starts from the same information.

Comment: See my comment below the answer - small change to the regex makes it work.

Comment: what is the original file name

Comment: Mark asked it already 24h ago, how difficult it is

Comment: sorry didn't see your reply
the original file name is: `home_repository_impl.dart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the possible `impl` part in the matched regex but don't use it in the replacement and do it case insensitive

```
    "body": [
      "class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/} implements ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*?)(impl)?$/${1:/pascalcase}/i} {",
      "final ${2:RemoteDataSource} remoteDataSource;",
      "${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*)/${1:/pascalcase}/}({required this.remoteDataSource});",
      "}"]
```

What is the use of all the `g`? You have no recurring matches.

**Edit** small modification based on Mark's comment. Match till end of string with `$`

**Edit** needed the **case insensitive** `i`, based on the given filename.

Comment: result is not what I'm expecting 
your answer result
`class HomeRepositoryImpl implements HomeRepositoryImpl {
  final HomeDataSource remoteDataSource;
  HomeRepositoryImpl({required this.remoteDataSource});
}`

Comment: i want it to be like that
`class HomeRepositoryImpl implements HomeRepository {
  final HomeDataSource remoteDataSource;
  HomeRepositoryImpl({required this.remoteDataSource});
}`

Comment: Try this instead: `${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*?)(Impl)?$/${1:/pascalcase}/}` for the after the `implements` part.  Note I added `$` to the end of the regex to make it work correctly.

Comment: still not working